# How to make Voila Dashboard not execute every time it runs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dashboard, voila

I've a somewhat large .ipynb notebook that I've decided to turn it into a dashboard using Voila.

It works just fine, however, it takes a lot of time to execute (around 20 minutes for 88 cell),
I've found out that even if I deploy it on Binder, it will execute every time someone tries to open it.

Is there anyway I can save the generated file so it won't take this long?