# Voila is not executing any cell of jupyter notebook, just showing outputs already present in notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, voila, jupyter-kernel, jupyter-extensions

There are two steps voila performs while rendering a jupyter notebook.

1. Voilà runs the code in the notebook and collects the outputs.
2. The notebook and its outputs are converted to HTML. By default, the notebook code cells are hidden.

In my case when I am trying to run jupyter notebook using voila, the first step is not happening.
Voila is jumping directly to second step skipping first.
I uninstalled voila and then reinstalled it again,even degraded voila to lower version but got no luck. Can somebody suggest how can I fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you know it is skipping the item you've listed as #1? Is it just this particular notebook or other Voila examples you've tried?

Comment: I'll add that if this is really happening, it would allow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70656501/8508004) to be answered if you or someone can figure out why/how.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example